# Is Stack Overflow using google search API?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is SO/SF/SU search not good or am I using it wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/is-so-sf-su-search-not-good-or-am-i-using-it-wrong)

Is Stack Overflow using google search API? and why or why not?

Comment: (I've closed as a duplicate - see the link for more info; but the short answer is "no"; see in particular Jeff's reply on that question)