# Search Stackoverflow questions using Google

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search, google

How can I search in stackoverflow using Google? Is there any keywords for searching in SO using google?

Comment: Dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/is-so-sf-su-search-not-good-or-am-i-using-it-wrong

Comment: You dropped this, e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `site:stackoverflow.com`, like so:

```
question text site:stackoverflow.com
```

That gets you [this search](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMI_enUS291US303&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=question+text+site:stackoverflow.com).

Enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

Use [this custom search](http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=018205968162215846785:7n6ajnwyz-i).