# Why does searching for "elephant muscles" return a post on hobbies with neither word present?

Tags: support, status-completed, search

In [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/is-so-sf-su-search-not-good-or-am-i-using-it-wrong), Jeff links to a [MSO search for "elephant muscles"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22elephant+muscles%22).  It returns two* questions: the post itself, and [this recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13558/what-non-programming-hobbies-do-you-have-closed) on people's hobbies.

The latter result has no occurance of either "elephant" or "muscles".  So why does the search return it?

(*) well, I guess there will be three results now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like only the first word in a phrase is being searched for. For example, this search brings up the same exact results as the one in the question:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22elephant+hoiuahsdohsdofhoiushdiofgh%22

Comment: I believe it's actually an `or` that's used. This has the same results: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q="hoiuahsdohsdofhoiushdiofgh+elephant"

Comment: ..and searching for "muscles" only yields the obvious two results.

Comment: Looks like that's what it's doing. Did this just recently break, or has this never worked and we've just never noticed?

Comment: ...which makes me want to find the missing elephant...

Comment: @Kyle: AFAIK, that's always been the behavior.

Comment: I noticed the `or`​​​ing earlier and it became quite annoying.

Comment: I believe it's always been this way, though.

Comment: @Eric: Consider finding out what the post said your reward for reaching 10k here on Meta :-)

Comment: @Kyle: You're an evil, evil man. Feel free to upvote me to oblivion in my quest to get there :)

Comment: @Eric: Evil? You're already over 1/3 the way there! If you keep gaining at the same rate, you'll be at 10k in 70 days.

Answer (score 3):

there is a deleted answer that contains the word "muscles"

edit: we were only testing for deleted parents (questions) not deleted children (answers). fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't you avoid searching deleted posts?

Comment: The real question is - do you consider this a feature or a bug? I've been looking for a way to search deleted posts as I (apparently erroneously) thought that the built-in search did not do that.

Comment: Oh, and while I do see the word "elephant" in the deleted post, I don't actually see "muscles". A page search brings up no matches.

Comment: ...and now I'm markedly curious as to the content of said post.

Comment: Jeff, here's a issue: do a search on SO for "VTD". Even when not logged in, this brings up questions with deleted answers from the spammer "anon_anon".