# How can I use stackoverflow more effectively?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [HOWTO: Writing Good Titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles)
>   [Is SO/SF/SU search not good or am I using it wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/is-so-sf-su-search-not-good-or-am-i-using-it-wrong)

When I search for some solutions to my problems, I search in the StackOverflow search box first, but there are thousands of questions.  Although I filter the questions by tag there are still many questions in front of me.

Sometimes I can't find any questions like mine, so then I write my question and wait for the answers.  But sometimes, one of the other users references a question which is same as my question!  This situation costs me my time.

Are there any recommendations for this situation?

Also, sometimes some questions have no answers because they are viewed too little, I think.  The problem is usually the title of question.  Are there any recommendations on writing more effective titles?

Comment: Regarding the search feature, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/is-so-sf-su-search-not-good-or-am-i-using-it-wrong

Comment: Regarding writing effective titles, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles

Answer (score 1):

For writing good titles follow the [dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles).

For searching more effectively copy the title you've written and paste it [here](http://www.google.com).